# Curious string comparison issue when string starts with a dash

Tags: apex, string

Try the following example in an anonymous Apex window:

```
String s = '- Default - ';
system.debug(s.CompareTo('Banner')<0); // True
system.debug(s<'Banner'); // False
s = '/ Default -';
system.debug(s.CompareTo('Banner')<0); // True
system.debug(s<'Banner'); // true
```

Lexically, '- Default' is smaller than Banner because the '-' is smaller than 'B'. And the CompareTo operator works accordingly. But a regular string compare is treating the '-' seemingly as a special case, thus '- Default' is being treated as larger than 'Banner'. I'm guessing that Apex is treating the dash as a hyphen and excluding it from the comparison? It obviously isn't ignoring punctuation as evidenced by the '/' example.

I haven't yet found any documentation in the Apex reference or elsewhere that specifies what is going on here.

So my question is: Is this expected behavior, and if so, does anyone know where it is documented?

Comment: I had some VERY weird experiencing with string handling and an inbound email handler, where comparing two strings will return true, but if I try to cast the string to an Int it will fail, even though its a valid integer.

Comment: Nice one! I played a bit, it behaves OK with test case narrowed down to '/', 'B', '-'. It starts to go bananas the moment you make '/x', 'Bx', '-x'. `compareTo()` returns same correct values in both cases (and they sort OK), it's "only" the `<` operator that acts weird. I've also noticed that '+' > '/' which is against ASCII table order. This stuff is so basic it should work irrespective of user's locale :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apex docs *do* state that comparison of strings using <, >, <=, and >= is performed according to the user's locale.

Java has a class [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) which performs locale-sensitive string comparisons.  I compiled this simple class and received the exact same results as your Apex less than comparisons:

```
import java.text.Collator;

public class TestCollator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance();
        System.out.println(myCollator.compare("- Default - ", "Banner") < 0); // False
        System.out.println(myCollator.compare("/ Default -", "Banner") < 0); // True
    }
}
```

I am honestly not certain of the relationship between Apex and Java, but if Apex logical comparison of strings is implemented to follow the behavior of Java Collator, then I would venture a guess that the results of your Apex code are expected behavior. It's certainly not the result you or I would have expected without further documentation by Salesforce, but it seems plausible that it's the intended result.

Comment: Thanks - I think you got it. Definitely not obvious.